# The flower is the rose./ The flower is roses./ The flowers are roses

Tags: expressions

‎When you are looking at a drawing with roses and want to tell the person looking it together the kind of the flowers, what do you say? Are the following sentences correct? Which one is best?

> The flower is the rose.

> The flower is roses.

> The flowers are roses.

Comment: Welcome! Proofreading questions are off topic here. Please edit to show what you currently understand about singular vs plural and about articles like "the."

Comment: I don't see this as proofreading.

Comment: If I'm looking at it together with someone, I'd probably say "this" or "that" instead of "the". "This flower is a rose." "These flowers are roses."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's a single rose the correct form is "The flower is a rose", if there are multiple roses then it would be "The flowers are roses".

Both "the flower is the rose" and "the flower is roses" would confuse a native speaker.